# gitlab-sonar-scanner: command not found for JS language

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab-ci, sonarqube-scan, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab CICD to run the pipelines. In order to analyse the code with sonarqube I am using `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with all config as below,

```
stages:
- analysis

sonarqube:
  stage: analysis
  image: ciricihq/gitlab-sonar-scanner
  variables:
    SONAR_URL: https://playground.altimetrik.com/sonarqube
    SONAR_ANALYSIS_MODE: issues
  script:
    - gitlab-sonar-scanner
```

I  have also added `sonar-project.properties`

I am always ending up with error saying,

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.3.1 (0aa5179e)
  on Gitlab-Pipeline 04bdd119
Using Shell executor...
Running on ip-10-101-102-187.ec2.internal...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 39bbd50 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
From https://gitlab.altimetrik.com/playground/node_js_usecasepg-ta1811536129881158
   39bbd50..99600f7  master     -> origin/master
Checking out 99600f70 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ gitlab-sonar-scanner
bash: line 57: gitlab-sonar-scanner: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

The same config wa working few days back, I am facing this error only in recent days. Can anyone help on this?

Thanks you...

Answer (score 0):

It Seems like the `sonar-scanner` has not been installed in your runner.
Please verify your runner to check this.

Reference : [installation steps](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)